# Redline BMX or is it Redline decals on something else?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I got this bicycle at a yard sale and thought it was a Redline BMX as that is what the decals on it are and same with head badge. Someone said it was not a Redline because the rear dropouts are not a Redline style. The original forks on it were genuine Redline forks as they had the RL stamp on the drops.

I had to replace forks with generic ones after the dealer had to cut the forks to get the headset off for an overhaul, because the plumb was rusted stuck inside. It says made in Taiwan on the headset and has Diamondback handlebars and grips. The serial number is on the rear dropout non chain side with another number on chain side rear drop out reading G0187 serial number is 7014544.

[image]

[image]

thanks for helping if you can!

Comment: Looking at this [link](http://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/info/187/), it doesn't match any serial number exactly. But the format is similar to Giant-made Redlines (and it doesn't look like that list is comprehensive). Redline is still in business (though taken over by some other company), so maybe you can ask them in an email?

Comment: updated the correct seial number.

Comment: Davis, Rich <RDavis@accellna.com>
To trekkhed@yahoo.com
Today at 3:44 PM

I cannot give you any information based on frame numbers. They are sealed up at the factory and we never see them. Based on the photo I can narrow it down to late 90’s. There are quite a few missing decals.

Comment: My red line circa 1986 says "redline" under the crank housing. Turn it over and look.

Comment: @PatrickO'connell This posting is approaching 3 years old.  Did you find any other information from other sources to help close this question ?

Comment: finally figured it is a schwinn predator and left it at that!

Answer (score 3):

GO187 is the date code from Giant (Taiwan manufacturer), which is Jan '87.

Frame looks to be an '87 Diamondback.

Comment: Welcome to SE - thank you for the contribution!  Feel free to try any of the other BMX identification questions because they often go unanswered.  Also please check out the [tour] at some point, to see how SE works.